# localStorage is saved but cannot retain data on browser after web page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, local-storage

I am trying to save chat message on localStorage (or sessionStorage) and display on web page, I can found the key-value pair stored in Devtool -> application -> localStorage, the message value update everytime when user sends the message and display on web page. However the content gone everytime when page reload. How to solve this?

Also what I am encountering is the push() to save messages to array will replaces instead of adds value, not sure if these 2 issues are related. Thanks.

pug file

```
#test2(style='height:200px; width:200px; border:1px solid #ccc')
```

js file

```
$('#sendMessage').on('click', function() {

        var msg = $('#message').val()
        var messages = [];
        console.log(typeof(messages)); //obj
        messages.push(msg);
        console.log(messages); //array value
        if (localStorage) {
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                localStorage.setItem('message', msg);
            }
            localStorage.setItem('username', $('#username').val());
            localStorage.setItem('date', currentTime());

            var cUser = localStorage.getItem('username');
            var cMsg = localStorage.getItem('message');
            var cTime = localStorage.getItem('date');

        } else {
            console.log('localStorage is not supported.');
        }

        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML += "<div>" + cUser + " : " + cMsg + "</div>";
        // Clear the field
        $('#message').val('');
    }); // End click
```

reload page lose data

```
    // Send Message
$('#sendMessage').on('click', function() {
    // get value
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var msg = $('#message').val();
    var time = currentTime();

    //check if localStorage works and create msgArray

    if (!localStorage) {

        console.log('localStorage is not supported.');

    } else {

        //check if there is existing message array in msgArray
        var msgArray = localStorage.getItem('message');
        //if there is NULL, setup msgArray = [], converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string
        if (JSON.stringify(msgArray) == 'null') {
            msgArray = [];
        } else {
            //else parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string
            msgArray = JSON.parse(msgArray);
        }
    }

    //add new message object to msgArray

    var newMsg = {
        msg: msg,
        username: username,
        time: time
    };

    msgArray.push(newMsg);
    // stringsfy the message and store it to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(msgArray));

    // dispaly current messages

    var cMsg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('message'));
    // console.log(cMsg); // should shows list of array with new added message objects
    // for (var i = 0, max = cMsg.length; i < max; i++) {

    //document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML += "<div>" + cMsg[i].username + " : " + cMsg[i].msg + " at " + cMsg[i].time + " </div>";
    $('#test2').append('<div class="well well-sm">' + cMsg[cMsg.length - 1].username + ' : ' + cMsg[cMsg.length - 1].msg + ' <span class="pull-right"><small id="date"> at ' + cMsg[cMsg.length - 1].time + '</small></span></div>');

    // load the bottom of message
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatArea");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

    // Clear the field
    $('#message').val('');
}); // End click
```

Comment: What is use of messages = []; as you saved msg in localStorage

Comment: You are overwriting message in localStorage, and also you are not retriving it from localStorage

Comment: It's a real time chat, if i didn't get thing wrong the user will submit messages, so it need to loop through all the messages the user sent and display on client side.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can you specify which part?

Comment: You are overwriting message in the localStorage here `localStorage.setItem('message', msg);`

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                localStorage.setItem('message', msg);
            }` is where you are overwrting, instead you should stringify the array and save in localStorage

Comment: Thank you all, the main issue now is the messages append on webpage are gone when I hit refresh..

Comment: @Blair They shouldn't be gone, as long as you don't do a `localStorage.removeItem` everything should be fine

Comment: @Icepickle I believe so, example like this one in w3c [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local), text didn't disappear after page reload, I basically test this code to my localhost, but text gone after reload, very weird.

Comment: @Blair Please update your code with the problems you have or create a new question. With your current code you would have that problem, because you seem to  have the basics wrong. Did you update something since you have received the answers on your question?

Comment: @Icepickle just update the code, no clue where is the error at..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your for loop, since you seem to be setting the same value as many times as you have messages (essentially that's worth nothing, setting it once should be enough)

Let's revisit your steps:

You are getting a value from an input element with id message, and saving it into the `msg` variable

```
var msg = $('#message').val()
```

You construct a new array, and push it in

```
var messages = [];
messages.push(msg);
```

And then you iterate the array, but re-use the `msg` variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem('message', msg);
}
```

So essentially, you did this:

```
localStorage.setItem('message', $('#message').val());
```

and nothing more. Maybe you wanted to get the array of messages first, and then add the new message to it, rather something like the following

```
function addMessage() {
  // get the potential array
  var messages = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('message') || '[]' );
  // add the message
  messages.push($('#message').val());
  // save the array as a string, using JSON.stringify
  localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify( messages));
  // empty the message value
  $('#message').val('');
  console.log(messages);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save some chat messages, I think you should make sure that all message are properly linked with the author's username and the time it was wrote.

You tried an array... For the messages, but not for the other infos.
And you misused the array.

LocalStorage will only store a string.
*Well... I think it can store objects too... But It is a habit of mine to always store strings.

This way, it always can be console logged fast, instead of bugging...*

So stringify the array before saving it.

And when you retreive it,
you have to parse it back to an array to be able to push a new message into it.

Ok... So will you try to synchronize 3 or more arrays?

I suggest ONE array of objects.
Each objects containing all the relevant infos linked to a particular message.

See comments in code.

```
$('#sendMessage').on('click', function() {

  // ...
  var chatWindow = $("#chatWindow");

  // Get all values now.
  var msg = $('#message').val();
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var time = moment().format("hh:mm:ss");


  if (!localStorage) {
    console.log('localStorage is not supported.');

  }else{
    // Retreive previous messages
    var messageArray = localStorage.getItem('message');


    // If there was none, set it as an array
    if(JSON.stringify(messageArray) == "null"){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(messageArray));
      messageArray = [];

      // If there was, get them back from string to an array of objects.
    }else{
      messageArray = JSON.parse(messageArray);
    }

    // Set the new message object.
    var newMsg = {msg:msg,
                  time:time,
                  username:username
                 }
    // Insert the new message object in the array.
    messageArray.push(newMsg);

    // Save the array as a string.
    var messagesStringified = JSON.stringify(messageArray);
    localStorage.setItem('message', messagesStringified);




    // I suppose that showing the messages from what is saved re-assures you about the saving...
    var cMsg = localStorage.getItem('message');

    // Empty chatWindow
    chatWindow.empty();

    // Loop through the messages.
    var allMessages = JSON.parse(cMsg);

    for(i=0;i<allMessages.length;i++){
      chatWindow.append("<div>" +
                        allMessages[i].time +
                        " | "+ allMessages[i].username +
                        " : " + allMessages[i].msg + "</div>");
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(messageArray));



    // Clear the field
    $('#message').val('');
  }
}); // End click


$('#clear').on('click', function() {
  localStorage.clear();
});
```

**Have a look on [**CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vZMXoE?editors=0011)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works great, but why will the append data lost after reload, since it store is localStorage already.

Comment: Because the page has reloaded! But you could loop thought the saved message on load to append them.